# SubServices in Apache Sling and Adobe AEM

Tags: osgi, aem

I would like to know the concept of subservices in OSGi, I tried to find the documentation, but not able to get any material in regards of AEM. I have snippet code.

```
ResourceResolverFactory.SUBSERVICE, "datawrite"
```

I tried to check in Felix console, I am able to find ResourceResolverFactory in service tab. But how can i check SUBSERVICE, and the various options available like datawrite etc. & what they standfor.

Thanks

Comment: Subservices are an Apache Sling concept that AEM uses, there's no concept of subservices in OSGi as far as I know. I have edited this questions' title accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me try and explain it in the context of Sling Authentication.

As of AEM6 there are changes in API to stop the abuse of AdministrativeResourceResolver which has been utilized by many developers to get admin resourceResolver without passing any credentials.

As this has been deprecated in AEM6 you need to call getServiceResourceResolver(..) and pass it with subservice name which is mapped to a user via ServiceUserMapper configuration.

e.g. a configuration for writeservice could be AEM-bundle:datawrite=datawriteuser. here we are saying that *datawrite* which is part of *AEM-bundle* is mapped to *datawriteuser* and the privilege available to this user is what will be used by *datawrite* service.

A Service can be composed of many subservice and those subservices will be mapped to different users quoting sling documentation *mail transfer service* can be composed of *smtp*, *queue*, *deliver* subsystem and these subsystem can be mapped to *mta:smtp*, *mta:queue*, *mta:deliver* users respectively.

Check these references:

[inside Blog entry](http://cqblog.inside-solutions.ch/2014/06/10/aem6-resourceresolver-access-in-services/)

[Sling Authentication](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/service-authentication.html)

Comment: Thanks, This blog seems contains information to do start some hands on

Answer (score 0):

It is the Name of the authentication information property providing the Subservice Name for the service requesting a resource resolver.

See http://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling7/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ResourceResolverFactory.html#SUBSERVICE